# Override Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js in custom theme not working

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, overrides, requirejs

I try to override the Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js file in my custom theme.

New location of the file:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Location of my requirejs-config.js file:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js
```

Contents of my requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': 'js/view/shipping'
        }
    }
};
```

I refreshed all caches and deployed static content but I keep getting the following 404 error in my console:

```
GET http://domain.loc/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/nl_NL/js/view/shipping.js
```

I also tried to move the requirejs-config.js file into my Magento_Checkout folder.

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When you want to create module at that time you need to create requirejs-config.js file to override js file in module.**

*`In theme you dont need to create require js file you can directly set js file in specific order of core module.`*

You dont need to create requirejs-config.js file in your theme.

Remove **requierejs-config.js** file from theme.

You have to set only js file in your theme.

Your path is correct.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js**

please run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
```

Remove var folder
Clear Browser cache.

Comment: I tried this before. The error is gone but it seems that the original file is not overwritten.

Comment: have u deploy and clear browser cache?